# Unassigned local variable/ alter XML Format

Tags: c#, sql, xml, using-statement, unassigned-variable

My program takes user input and uses it to create a query. The results of that query will then be put into an XML file with XElements based on their selections. I have a string `staff` which i set equal to the value of staffType.

**Where staff is declared w/ snippet of query code:**

```
        using (
            var conn = new SqlConnection("Server=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;Database=KUDERDEV;User ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;Password= xxxxxxxx;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;")
            )
        {
            conn.Open();
            bool quit = false;
            string choice;
            string staff;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            while (!quit)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sort by staffType: K12Staff, psStaff, WFStaff or none?");
                string staffType = Console.ReadLine();
                staff = staffType;
                if (staffType == "K12Staff")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sort by code, date, both, or none?");
                    choice = Console.ReadLine();
                    switch (choice)
                    {
                        case "code":
                            Console.WriteLine("Sort by code1 or code2?");
                            string codeCol = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("Enter desired code");
                            string code = Console.ReadLine();
                            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Staff WHERE (Staff." + @codeCol + "='" + @code + "') AND staffType ='" + @staffType + "' FOR XML PATH('staff'), ROOT('k12Staff')", conn);
                            quit = true;
                            staff = staffType;
                            break;
```

When the query string is complete, I go into another using statement without closing the first one to write the XML file. Here I want to change the format of the XML (XElement) depending on which staffType was chosen.

**Writing the XML file snippet:**

```
        using (cmd)
        {
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader())
            {
                var doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
                string path = @"Staff." + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".xml";
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
                {
                    //if (staff == "k12Staff")
                    XNamespace ns = "http://specification.sifassociation.org/Implementation/na/3.2/html/CEDS/K12/K12_k12Staff.html";
                    var root = new XElement(ns + "k12Staff");

                    foreach (var d in doc.Descendants("staff"))
                    {
                        root.Add(new XElement(ns + "staff",
                                    new XElement(ns + "identity",
                                        new XElement(ns + "name",
                                            new XElement(ns + "firstName", first),
                                            new XElement(ns + "lastName", last)
                                            )
                                        ),
                                    new XElement(ns + "employment",
                                        new XElement(ns + "positionTitle", position)
                                            ),
                                    new XElement(ns + "assignment",
                                        new XElement(ns + "leaID", leaID),
                                        new XElement(ns + "schoolID", schoolID)
                                                ),
                                    new XElement(ns + "contact",
                                        new XElement(ns + "phoneNumberList",
                                            new XElement(ns + "number", phone),
                                            new XElement(ns + "phoneNumberIndicator", indicator)
                                        ),
                                        new XElement(ns + "emailList",
                                            new XElement(ns + "email", email)
                                            )
                                            ),
                                    new XElement(ns + "delete", delete)
```

Then if the staffType was something different such as "psStaff" then I would change the format of the XML (XElement) to have different names, positions, etc.

**So it would be like:**

```
 if(staff == "k12Staff"){
         format xml here...
 }
 else if (staff == "psStaff"){
         format xml here....
 }
```

etc etc..

**My Problem:**

In the previous example, my code has `if(staff == "k12Staff")` but I am told that it is an assigned local variable. I have tried declaring staff outside of the using statements as well as trying to use `staff` in a using statement like so `using(staff)` which is how I used my `cmd` variable. How come my program recognizes `cmd` but not `staff`?

Comment: Your title says "**un**assigned-local-varible. I just gave an answer to this. But then I read your question once again and in your text you write about a problem with an assigned variable? So please clarify. And I hope, that my answer is not entirely aside...

Comment: Hi Brandon, if my answer was helpful it would be very kind of you to vote it up and mark it as accepted answer. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not post the entire code, so it is not possble to say, where your variable `staff` should get a value and why it doesn't.

Not assigned means: existing but never got a value...

Try the following: At the place, where you declare your variable change this:

```
    string staff="defaultValue";
```

On the place where you handle the variable's content change this:

```
 if(staff == "k12Staff"){
         format xml here...
 }
 else if (staff == "psStaff"){
         format xml here....
 }
 else if (staff == "defaultValue"){
      //What ever is to be done if all attempts to set "staff" did not work
      //You must set a stop mark before your `while (!quit)` and step through.
      //There is at least one situation, where `staff` is not set to any value...
      //If there's a bug you must fix this, if this is allowed to happen, solve it here...
 }
```

Comment: I didn't want to post the whole code because there is almost 400 lines of it.  The first snippet is repeated over and over but with different variables. If you'd like, I can send you the whole code.

Comment: @BrandonLumsden, did you try my suggestion? Which value is there in "staff"? Is it "defaultValue"? If yes you'll have to step through to find, why your "staff" is not set to a proper value...

Comment: looks like after all this time I just needed to declare staff with a value instead of `string staff;`. Crazy how it took 2 days of searching for something so small. Thanks.

Comment: @BrandonLumsden, glad to read that I could help you solve this problem! Happy coding!